# Import django doesn't work? Pythonpath?

Tags: python, django, pythonpath

I'm running Windows with Python 2.7 and (I believe) Django 1.0. I installed Django using the Bitnami Djangostack. The strange thing is, when I typed "import django" in python, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
```

I searched online for an answer, but all of the answers I found were "django needs to be in your PYTHONPATH." I'm new to Python, so I don't know what this means. Can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you need to [install Django under Python 2.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/install/) as well.

Comment: Maybe they've changed the page, but it doesn't mention how to "install Django under Python 2.7 as well". Can you explain?

Comment: I think this may mean to use `pip install Django`, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/install/#installing-official-release

Answer (score 0):

if you type the following at the command line what does it say?

```
python --version
```

My guess is that bitnami installed into one python version and you are using another, or when they installed it they didn't put it in the pythonpath. I don't know much about the bitnami stack but have you looked at these instructions?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/install/